# Oracle 11g : Meta data query very slow

Tags: sql, oracle, metadata

I have this view that should display comments and constraints (including check conditions where applicable) for the columns of some tables in a schema.

**Essentially I'm (left ) joining ALL_COL_COMMENTS to ALL_CONS_COLUMNS to ALL_CONSTRAINTS.**

However, this is really slow for some reason ( takes around 10 seconds ) even though I have a very small number of tables ( just 7 ) , very small number of columns (  58 columns in total ). So the query returns few results. And it's still slow. What can I do ?

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW "MYDB"."COMMENTS_VIEW" ("TABLE_NAME", "COLUMN_NAME", "COMMENTS", "CONSTRAINT_TYPE", "CHECK_CONDITION") AS 
  SELECT r.TABLE_NAME, r.COLUMN_NAME, r.COMMENTS, DECODE(q.CONSTRAINT_TYPE,'P', 'Primary Key', 'C', 'Check Constraint', 'R', 'Referential Integrity Constraint' ), q.SEARCH_CONDITION AS CHECK_CONDITION
      FROM  ALL_COL_COMMENTS r -- ALL_COL_COMMENTS has the COMMENTS
          LEFT JOIN ALL_CONS_COLUMNS p ON (p.TABLE_NAME = r.TABLE_NAME AND p.OWNER = 'MYDB' AND p.COLUMN_NAME = r.COLUMN_NAME) -- ALL_CONS_COLUMNS links COLUMNS to CONSTRAINTS
          LEFT JOIN ALL_CONSTRAINTS q ON (q.OWNER = 'MYDB' AND q.CONSTRAINT_NAME = p.CONSTRAINT_NAME AND q.TABLE_NAME = p.TABLE_NAME AND (q.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'C' OR q.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'P' OR q.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'R' ) ) -- this gives us INFO on CONSTRAINTS
    WHERE r.OWNER = 'MYDB' 
        AND 
    r.TABLE_NAME IN ('TABLE1', 'TABLE2', 'TABLE3', 'TABLE4', 'TABLE5', 'TABLE6', 'TABLE7')
        AND
    r.COLUMN_NAME NOT IN ('CREATED', 'MODIFIED', 'CREATED_BY', 'MODIFIED_BY') 
      ORDER BY r.TABLE_NAME, r.COLUMN_NAME, r.COMMENTS;
```

Answer (score 4):

Ensure the dictionary and fixed object statistics are up-to-date.  Checking for up-to-date statistics is a good first step for almost any SQL performance problem.  The dictionary and fixed objects are unusual, and there's a good chance nobody has considered gathering statistics on them before.

```
begin
    dbms_stats.gather_fixed_objects_stats;
    dbms_stats.gather_dictionary_stats;
end;
/
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to join on table, and column ids instead of names where possible.  Even OWNER if you can.  Example:

```
    ON p.TABLE_ID = r.TABLE_ID
```

Also, you are selecting from objects that are already views of who knows how many underlying tables.  The query optimizer is probably having a hard time (and maybe giving up in some aspects).  Try to translate your query into using the base tables.

Answer (score 0):

I would either use a query profiler, or (simpler) just remove parts of your query until it gets super fast.  For example, remove the DECODE() call, maybe that's doing it.